# MongoDB aggregation of array in single document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have 3 collections to aggregate.

1st is colors collection with colors details, name value etc

```
{
    {
        _id: 1,   <- mongoose objectId
        name: red
    },
    {
        _id: 2,   <- mongoose objectId
        name: green
    }
}
```

2nd is products (products details)

```
{
    {
        _id: Id777, <- mongoose objectId
        productName: test prod 777
    },
    {
        _id: Id888, <- mongoose objectId
        productName: test prod 888
    }
}
```

and 3rd it move collection. here is the array of object to **aggregation**

```
{
    ....other fields here
    items: [
        {
            _id: an mongoose id,
            itemId: Id777 <- in products collection,
            itemColor: 1 <- id in colors collection,
            coutn: 7,
            ....other fields
        },
        {
            _id: an mongoose id,
            itemId: Id888 <- in products collection,
            itemColor: 2 <- id in colors collection
            cout: 10
            ....other fields
        }
    ]
}
```

this code works good if I get many documents from collection.
but when I try to get only 1 document by _id, its didn't working

```
const query = {
    $and: [
        {appId: req.user.appId},
        {_id: req.params._id} <- here is mongodb id
    ],

const moves = await ProductMoves.aggregate([
  { $match: query }, // this is my query
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "items.itemId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "itemId"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "colors",
      localField: "items.itemColor",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "itemColor"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "items.itemId": { $arrayElemAt: ["$itemId.productName", 0] },
      "items.itemColor": { $arrayElemAt: ["$itemColor.name", 0] }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      items: { $push: "$items" },
      addedDate: { $first: "$addedDate" }
    }
  }
])
```

So, how I can get only 1 document by _id and aggregate it? Thank you!

Comment: You have `appId` in ProductMoves?

Comment: `req.params._id` is probably a string, is the `_id` in the documents also string?